# Given $n$ points and a random point $P$ in a unit hypercube, what is the chance of any of the $n$ points being within distance $d$ around $P$?

Tags: probability, geometric-probability

Given:

- $n$ points in a unit hypercube
- A random point $P$ in the same unit hypercube (assuming uniform random, but I'd also be interested in having a general solution that works for any kind of randomness)
- A maximum distance $d$ (assuming Euclidean distance, but I'd also be interested in having a general solution that works for any distance metric)
- Any dimensionality

What is the chance of any of the $n$ points being within distance $d$ around the random point $P$? I can approximate the solution numerically, but I am wondering if there's an analytic solution to this problem.

This problem has the interesting property that multiple (of those $n$) points that are in the same location don't increase the chance at all; points that are very close to each other don't increase it much; the more evenly points are spread, the higher the chance.

Comment: It would be helpful if you clarified what kind of answer would be helpful. Assuming that $P$ is distributed uniformly then you are asking for $$ \mathop{\rm vol} \bigl(  Q \cap \bigcup_1^n B_d(x_i) \bigr). $$ Here $Q$ is the hypercube and $B_d(x)$ is the Euclidean $d$-ball around $x$. If you think about the $3$-dimensional case then it is clear that this is a complicated function of the positions of the $x_i$.

Comment: Thank you @JamieRadcliffe, if I'm reading that right, that is the volume of the union of all (hyper)spheres of radius $d$ around my $n$ points, intersected with the unit (hyper)cube - makes sense so far. I think the answer that I'm looking for is: How would I go about constructing the _complicated function_ that you are mentioning? The volume of a single point is trivial, but the volume of the whole union, and finally the volume of the intersected union, I have no idea how to approach.

Comment: @TickaJules: You seem to be treating the $n$ points as random; but in the question only $P$ is random; the $n$ points are given.